Flutter windows build firebase and CMake error
I recently updated my Flutter to the newest version (3.24.3)
Now when I want to build my project as a windows app, it will show me these errors and close the building process:
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:119 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    D:/programing/Flutter/admin_dashboard/build/windows/x64/extracted/firebase_cpp_sdk_windows

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_app".


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_app


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_auth".


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_auth


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_storage".


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_storage


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:125 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "firebase_firestore".


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:126 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/firebase_core/windows/CMakeLists.txt:127 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  firebase_firestore


Error: Unable to generate build files

This is my pubspec.yaml :
name: soundify_admin
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  window_manager: ^0.4.2
  cloud_firestore: ^5.3.0
  toastification: ^2.2.0
  http: ^1.2.2
  flare_flutter: ^3.0.2
  firebase_storage: ^12.2.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  image_picker_windows: ^0.2.1+1
  filepicker_windows: ^2.1.4
  audioplayers: ^6.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  mime: any
  firebase_core: ^3.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/resolution-aware-images

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/asset-from-package

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/to/font-from-package


This is my main.dart :
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:soundify_admin/pages/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toastification/toastification.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    await WindowManager.instance.ensureInitialized();
    await WindowManager.instance.center();
    await WindowManager.instance.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
    await WindowManager.instance.setSize(const Size(1300, 750));
    await WindowManager.instance.setResizable(true);
    await WindowManager.instance.setMaximizable(true);
    await WindowManager.instance.setMinimumSize(const Size(1100, 750));

    await WindowManager.instance.setIcon("assets/images/icon.ico");

    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (error, stack) {
    print('Error: $error');
    print('Stack trace: $stack');
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ToastificationWrapper(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: (_) {
          windowManager.startDragging();
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: FutureBuilder(
            future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('Error initializing Firebase'),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return const SplashScreen();
              }

              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


My Visual Studio's version is 2022
I tried to remove the CMake files and recover them by flutter create . command but it didn't work.
I tried downgrading but neither that worked.
